# PYTHON: Move a value in a dictionary from one key to another key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

If I have a dictionary say:

```
dictionary = {'blue': [ [0,1], [0,2] ] , 'red': [ [0,3], [0,4] ] }
```

How would I move a `blue` value say `[0,1]` to the `red` without leaving behind a copy in `blue` without hardcoding the delete ( so if I had a different list of a hundred values and want to move a value from one key to another it should also work in that way ).

I want the output to look this:

```
dictionary = {'blue': [ [0,2] ] , 'red': [ [0,3], [0,4], [0,1] ] }
```

EDIT:

Ok, since people are asking for context:

My dictionary is:

```
d = {' . ': [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 9], [1, 1],
             [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], [2, 1], [2, 2],
             [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [2, 9], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3],
             [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [3, 9], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3],
             [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [4, 9], [5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3],
             [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [5, 9], [6, 0], [6, 1], [6, 2], [6, 3],
             [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6], [6, 7], [6, 8], [6, 9], [7, 0], [7, 1], [7, 2], [7, 3],
             [7, 4], [7, 5], [7, 6], [7, 7], [7, 8], [7, 9], [8, 0], [8, 1], [8, 2], [8, 3],
             [8, 4], [8, 5], [8, 6], [8, 7], [8, 8], [8, 9], [9, 0], [9, 1], [9, 2], [9, 3],
             [9, 4], [9, 5], [9, 6], [9, 7], [9, 8], [9, 9]],
     ' X ': [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0]]}
```

I want to move [3,0] from ' X ' to ' . ' and don't want it being left behind there.

I don't want this hardcoded as I want to do so with other values back and forth.

Conditions to move values:

If a value has a certain neighbours

ie [1,0] neighbours are [0,0], [2,0], [0,1] and so on

so if it has a certain number of neighbours or doesn't I move it to either ' X ' or ' . '

This is so I can plot the coordinates with the corresponding label --> 'X' or '.'

Comment: There isn’t a shortcut for this.

Comment: `dictionary['blue'].remove([0,1]); dictionary['red'].append([0,1])`?

Comment: @Rawing OP said without hard coding the delete.

Comment: @direprobs Meaning what? They want to move a random element?

Comment: @Rawing I'm not sure what OP exactly expects, but the question states  _"without hardcoding the delete..."_

Comment: Updated hopefully this is more helpful @Rawing

Comment: How do you select the items to move?

Comment: If certain conditions are met i.e whether a coordinates neighbours are ' X ' or ' . '. If the conditions are met, I want to move the value @LaurentLAPORTE

Comment: @EpicBoss: Sorry but it is still not clear…

Comment: @EpicBoss your update still doesn't clarify the conditions needed to move something from one to the other. Are you going to write code that accepts input for what to move or...?

Comment: @birryree I updated with conditions

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I updated my post. Neighbours are just touching coordinates so if you plot all the coordinates on a grid, whichever coordinates surround the point are its neighbours. So what I am doing is counting the neighbours and then if it has a certain amount of neighbours, I want it to go to the other key. Later I will plot the coordinates to spell out a grid

Comment: Are you trying to create something like [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_life)?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to store the coords as the keys and the `'.'` and `'X'` as the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're allowed to change the dictionary (this seems to be a homework assignment), but I think it would probably be better to store the coords as the keys and the symbols as the values of the dictionary.

```
# A dictionary comprehension to create a dict.
# Coords as the keys and '.' as the values.
board = {(x, y): '.' for x in range(10) for y in range(10)}

# To change the value just set some coords to 'X' or '.'.
board[(2, 3)] = 'X'

# Print the board.
for y in range(10):
    for x in range(10):
        print(board[(x, y)], end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use tuples for internal lists and OrderedDict for external:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dictionary = {'blue': OrderedDict.fromkeys([(0, 1), (0, 2)]),
              'red': OrderedDict.fromkeys([(0, 3), (0, 4)])}
```

Then you could still iterate the values of the external dictionary one by one:

```
for pair in dictionary['blue']:
    print(pair)
```

and inserting/deleting a pair would take O(1) on average.

Answer (score 0):

Just a generic function to move values between keys. You should deal with the exception outside the function.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vim:fenc=utf-8


def moveBetweenKeys(dictionary, src_key, dest_key, value):
    """
    Move the value <value> from the key <src_key> to the key <dest_key>
    Raises ValueError if the value was not found in the list of the keywork
    <src_key>
    """

    src_list = dictionary[src_key]
    dest_list = dictionary[dest_key]

    if value not in src_list:
        raise ValueError("'%s' was not found in the list '%s'" % (value, src_key))

    src_list.remove(value)
    dest_list.append(value)
```